# Fixed height of images in slick.js

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have searched for several hours to customize slick.js to make the height fixed of slider images but failed. The images are of variable heights, so my site page always moves which is odd.
Anyone there to help that where should I customize? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `adaptiveHeight: false` while [initializing slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings).
Additionally, you might need to set a fixed width on your `slider div`